# Is it possible to get classes from root module in gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have multi module spring boot project. Root project is "BookStore", and child module is "api". I try to use in "api" classes from "bookstore". But I have error:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':api'.
> Project with path ':BookStore' could not be found in project ':api'.

My root settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.3.3.RELEASE"
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'BookStore'

include 'api'
```

build.gradle of the root:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

allprojects {
    group = 'com.aleksandr'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    description = 'BookStore'

}
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply {
        plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
    }
}
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation project(':api')
}
```

And build.gradle of the child module:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(":BookStore")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get classes from root module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a dependency from a subproject (here, `api`) to the rootProject, you must use one of the following dependency notations:

**child module build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    api(project(":"))  // ":" is the identifier for the rootProject
    
    // OR 
    
    api(rootProject)   // "rootProject" varible points to the root Project instance.
    
}
```

But there is another issue in your example:  you are creating a dependency cycle between the rootProject and `api` subproject, which is not allowed.

IMO, your `api` subproject should not depend on root project.

Comment: So, is there a problem with architecture?

Comment: yes it seems so. I assume your root project, "BookStore", is the main application project containing the @SpringbootApplication entry point class;   this project "consumes" the subprojcets, like `api` . but why should `api` depend on this main application project?? there is something wrong here I think